# Issue with AJAX form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Required the form to be submitted via an ajax call and you will intercept the result and update your page. You never leave the index page.

I'm having trouble having the ajax call working

```
        <form action="/cart" method="post" id="addProduct">
            Quantity: <input type="number" name="quantity">
            <button type="submit">Add to Cart</button>
            <input type="hidden" name="productid" value="{{id}}">
            <input type="hidden" name="update" value="0">
        </form>





         var form = $('#addProduct');
            form.submit(function(e){
               e.preventDefault();
                 $.ajax({
                     type: "POST",
                     url: "/cart",
                     data: form,
                     dataType: "json",
                 success: function(e) {
                     window.location.href = "/";
               }
            });
         })
```

Comment: What is your specific problem? Try adding `error: function() {...}` to the `ajax` options to check if there is any error, use logs inside it. Also, you may need `data: form.serialize()`. [Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

Comment: What do you want to do with ajax call response? Right now, you are just navigating away from the page with the line:  window.location.href = "/";  You should replace this line with the code to update the page or do something else with the ajax response

Answer (score 1):

you can use

JavaScript

```
new FormData(document.querySelector('form'))
```

form-serialize (https://code.google.com/archive/p/form-serialize/)

```
serialize(document.forms[0]);
```

jQuery

```
$("form").serializeArray()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are changing the whole meaning of the ajax call. Ajax call is used for updating something without page refresh. In your case on success, you are changing the URL which is not right. Remove  `window.location.href = "/";` from your code and try to append messages or alert something like `alert('Product is added to cart');`

Comment: Code for updating things should be in the URL you are providing in your AJAX call in your case it is cart page.

Answer (score 0):

To update your document after success you can use append(e) to update your DOM

```
<form  method="post" id="addProduct">
            Quantity: <input type="number" name="quantity">
            <button type="submit">Add to Cart</button>
            <input type="hidden" name="productid" value="2">
            <input type="hidden" name="update" value="0">
        </form>

    <div id="display">

    </div>



    $(function(){

            $("#addProduct").submit(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
           var quantity = $(this).children("input[name=quantity]").val();
           var productid = $(this).children("input[name=productid]").val();
           var update = $(this).children("input[name=update]").val();
               $.ajax({
                  type:"post",
                  url:"/cart.php",
                  data:{update:update,quantity:quantity,productid:productid},
                  success: function(feedback){
                      $("#display").html(feedback);
                  },
                  error: function(err){
                    alert("error");
                  }
               });

            });
    });
```

I update my answer and i use the div with id display to show my data return from ajax success

Comment: Can I have an example ??

Answer (score 0):

Your ajax call is not sending data to the server. Use formdata object or serialize() to get form input values then send it to the server.

Use

```
var form = new FormData($('#addProduct')[0]);
```

OR

```
var form =  $("'#addProduct").serialize();
```

Instead of

```
var form = $('#addProduct');
```

And on success, send response from server and update your DOM in success function. Don't use window.location.href = "/";

Comment: @xerox , normally we use ajax to perform a task without page loading or when we have to update some DOM elements or values. we don't need to reload entire page. In your case you have to send updated values in JSON object and you can update your form values on success.